# Dell Specific Keyboard Layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I recently installed ubuntu on my daily machine, Dell Latitude E5470. The problem is, it has a specific keyboard layout. I use the normal Portuguese layout. So there are a few symbols that I cannot use. Need a fix ASAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and select "Dell Latitude laptop" as the keyboard model.

Hopefully that will make a difference after next reboot.